# Table of numbers and their divisors

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I want to create a table of random numbers and their divisors. The random numbers are given by

```
TableForm[{{Subscript[m, 1] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
 Subscript[n, 1] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}]}, 
 {Subscript[m, 2] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
 Subscript[n, 2] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}]}, 
 {Subscript[m, 3] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
 Subscript[n, 3] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}]}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"m", "n"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

So far so good. A neat table with delimiters for the headings. But when I try to add the divisors it all goes wrong:

```
TableForm[{{Subscript[m, 1] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
 Subscript[n, 1] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
   Divisors[Subscript[m, 1]], 
   Divisors[Subscript[n, 1]]}, {Subscript[m, 2] = 
RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
   Subscript[n, 2] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
   Divisors[Subscript[m, 2]], Divisors[Subscript[n, 2]]}, 
 {Subscript[m, 3] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
  Subscript[n, 3] = RandomInteger[{2, 50}], 
   Divisors[Subscript[m, 3]], Divisors[Subscript[n, 3]]}}, 
TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"m", "n", "divisors[m]", 
"divisors[n]"}}, 
TableAlignments -> Center]
```

I want the heading delimiters to remain, but they disappear; and I'd like the divisors to appear in a comma-delimited horizontal list (for example `Divisors[4]` would produce `1,2,4` rather than a vertical list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
table = RandomInteger[{2, 50}, {3, 2}];
TableForm[Join[table, Map[Row[Divisors[#], " "] &, table, {-1}], 2], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"m", "n", "divisors[m]", "divisors[n]"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @kglr. I'm struggling to incorporate this solution into other forms of table (mainly because I don't understand what you did!) I'd also like to create a table that lists `n` from `1` to `25` in one column, and `Divisors[n]` in the second column, formatted as you did in your answer above.

Comment: @Richard, `table` is a 3X2 matrix of numbers as in your first example. `Map[Divisors, table, {-1}]` gives the divisors of each entry in that matrix. I wrapped each list of divisors with `Row[..., " "]` so that each divisor list is displayed horizontally. A simpler form using the options `TableDirections` is `TableForm[Join[table, Map[Divisors, table, {-1}], 2], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"m", "n", "divisors[m]", 
    "divisors[n]"}, None}, TableAlignments -> Center, 
 TableDirections -> {Column, Row, Row}]` but, due to a glitch/bug it doesn't display the dividers.

Comment: ... so i had to use `Row` around the inner lists. The example in your comment can be done using `TableForm[Transpose[{Range[25], Row[Divisors[#]] & /@ Range[25]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"n", "divisors[n]"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]`.